# Summing up the records as per given conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access

I have a table like below, What I need that for any particular fund and up to any particular date logic will sum the amount value. Let say I need the sum for 3 dates as 01/28/2015,03/30/2015 and 04/01/2015. Then logic will check for up to first date how many records are there in table . If it found more than one record then it'll sum the amount value. Then for next date it'll sum up to the next date but from the previous date it had summed up.

```
Id Fund   Date         Amount
1   A   01/20/2015      250
2   A   02/28/2015      300
3   A   03/20/2015      400
4   A   03/30/2015      200
5   B   04/01/2015      500
6   B   04/01/2015      600
```

I want result to be like below

```
Id   Fund    Date        SumOfAmount
1     A    02/28/2015      550
2     A    03/30/2015      600
3     B    04/01/2015     1100
```

Comment: So is your DBMS MySQL or SQL Server? Why both in tags?

Comment: sorry it is sql server only

Comment: Am i the only one who doesnt understand the result? Why 550 for 01/28/2015, why 600 for 03/30/2015 , why 1100 for 04/01/2015? Wait, the last is the only thing that makes sense.

Comment: If I understand correctly, line 1 in the results is incorrect and should be '02/28/2015'.  This is the total of all records prior to 2/28.  The next line shows the total of all records after 2/28 up to 3/30 and the last line shows the total of all records after 3/30 up to 4/1.

Comment: I fully agree with Grax. I just upvoted his comment.

Comment: @Grax thanks for your understanding.I am sorry for that confusion.you are correct on your understanding. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, it seems that you want to select a set of dates, and then for each fund and selected date, get the sum of the fund amounts from the selected date to the previous selected date. Here is the result set I think you should be expecting:

```
Fund    Date        SumOfAmount
A       2015-02-28  550.00
A       2015-03-30  600.00
B       2015-04-01  1100.00
```

Here is the code to produce this output:

```
DECLARE @Dates TABLE
(
    SelectedDate DATE PRIMARY KEY 
)

INSERT INTO @Dates 
VALUES
     ('02/28/2015')
    ,('03/30/2015')
    ,('04/01/2015')

DECLARE @FundAmounts TABLE
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,Fund VARCHAR(5)
    ,Date DATE
    ,Amount MONEY
);

INSERT INTO @FundAmounts
VALUES
     (1, 'A', '01/20/2015', 250)
    ,(2, 'A', '02/28/2015', 300)
    ,(3, 'A', '03/20/2015', 400)
    ,(4, 'A', '03/30/2015', 200)
    ,(5, 'B', '04/01/2015', 500)
    ,(6, 'B', '04/01/2015', 600);

SELECT 
    F.Fund
    ,D.SelectedDate AS Date
    ,SUM(F.Amount) AS SumOfAmount
FROM
(
    SELECT
        SelectedDate
        ,LAG(SelectedDate,1,'1/1/1900') OVER (ORDER BY SelectedDate ASC) AS PreviousDate
    FROM @Dates
) D
JOIN
    @FundAmounts F
    ON
        F.Date BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY,1,D.PreviousDate) AND D.SelectedDate
GROUP BY
    D.SelectedDate
    ,F.Fund
```

EDIT: Here is alternative to the `LAG` function for this example:

```
FROM
(
    SELECT
        SelectedDate
        ,ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 SelectedDate FROM @Dates WHERE SelectedDate < Dates.SelectedDate ORDER BY SelectedDate DESC),'1/1/1900') AS PreviousDate
    FROM @Dates Dates
) D
```

Comment: @Brenan thanks for your response. But the thing is I need to execute this query in vba. Query is working fine. there are temporary tables in vba which are used in this query but as per the query LAG functionality works only with sql.. How can I execute it with vba??

Comment: I edited my answer to include an alternative to the LAG function. But to answer your question about executing with VBA, you may want to encapsulate this logic within a SQL stored procedure and then call the stored procedure from code. It would be best to use an ORM like EntityFramework, Linq2SQL, or NHibernate. But at the very least, you should use SqlParameters to avoid SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Documentation for SqlParamter class: [SqlParameter Class(System.Data.SqlClient)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: A good discussion on choosing between EntityFramework and Linq2SQL:  [Linq2SQL vs EF in .net Framework 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4329991/linq2sql-vs-ef-in-net-framework-4-0)

Comment: I would recommend Linq2SQL if you're just starting out with ORM's and if you don't foresee a change to a different RDMS.

Comment: Are you sure that the alternative you provided is working? Please confirm me as because i am not getting the desired result. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I have tested the alternative and it is working. How do your results differ from the results posted in this answer?

Answer (score 1):

If i change your incorrect sample data to ...

```
CREATE TABLE TableName
    ([Id] int, [Fund] varchar(1), [Date] datetime, [Amount] int)
;

INSERT INTO TableName
    ([Id], [Fund], [Date], [Amount])
VALUES
    (1, 'A', '2015-01-28 00:00:00', 250),
    (2, 'A', '2015-01-28 00:00:00', 300),
    (3, 'A', '2015-03-30 00:00:00', 400),
    (4, 'A', '2015-03-30 00:00:00', 200),
    (5, 'B', '2015-04-01 00:00:00', 500),
    (6, 'B', '2015-04-01 00:00:00', 600)
;
```

this query using GROUP BY works:

```
SELECT MIN(Id) AS Id,   
       MIN(Fund) AS Fund,
       [Date],        
       SUM(Amount) AS SumOfAmount
FROM dbo.TableName t
WHERE [Date] IN ('01/28/2015','03/30/2015','04/01/2015')
GROUP BY  [Date]
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e9c89/1/0)

Comment: It's kind of had to tell, but the line that says, "Then for next date it'll sum up to the next date but from the previous date it had summed up," seems at odds with the idea that he would only want records equal to the provided dates.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @TableName table([Id] int, [Fund] varchar(1), [Date] datetime, [Amount] int)
declare @Sample table([SampleDate] datetime)


INSERT INTO @TableName
    ([Id], [Fund], [Date], [Amount])
VALUES
    (1, 'A', '20150120 00:00:00', 250),
    (2, 'A', '20150128 00:00:00', 300),
    (3, 'A', '20150320 00:00:00', 400),
    (4, 'A', '20150330 00:00:00', 200),
    (5, 'B', '20150401 00:00:00', 500),
    (6, 'B', '20150401 00:00:00', 600)

INSERT INTO @Sample ([SampleDate])
values ('20150128 00:00:00'), ('20150330 00:00:00'), ('20150401 00:00:00')


-- select * from @TableName
-- select * from @Sample

;WITH groups AS ( 
    SELECT [Fund], [Date], [AMOUNT], MIN([SampleDate]) [SampleDate] FROM @TableName
    JOIN @Sample ON [Date] <= [SampleDate]
    GROUP BY [Fund], [Date], [AMOUNT])
SELECT [Fund], [SampleDate], SUM([AMOUNT]) FROM groups
GROUP BY [Fund], [SampleDate]
```

Explanation:

- The CTE `groups` finds the earliest `SampleDate` which is later than (or equals to) your
  data's date and enriches your data accordingly, thus giving them the group to be summed up in.
- After that, you can group on the derived date.

Answer (score 0):

**Initially i have used Row_number and month function to pick max date of every month and in 2nd cte i did sum of amounts and joined them..may be this result set matches your out put**

```
declare @t table (Id int,Fund Varchar(1),Dated date,amount int)

insert into @t (id,Fund,dated,amount) values (1,'A','01/20/2015',250),
(2,'A','01/28/2015',300),
(3,'A','03/20/2015',400),
(4,'A','03/30/2015',200),
(5,'B','04/01/2015',600),
(6,'B','04/01/2015',500)

;with cte as (
select ID,Fund,Amount,Dated,ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
  (PARTITION BY DATEDIFF(MONTH, '20000101', dated)ORDER BY dated desc)AS RN from @t
  group by ID,Fund,DATED,Amount
  ),
  CTE2 AS 
  (select  SUM(amount)Amt from @t
    GROUP BY MONTH(dated))
  ,CTE3 AS 
  (Select Amt,ROW_NUMBER()OVER (ORDER BY amt)R from cte2)
 ,CTE4 AS 
 (
        Select DISTINCT C.ID As ID,
        C.Fund As Fund,
        C.Dated As Dated
        ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY RN ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))R
         from cte C INNER JOIN CTE3 CC ON c.RN = CC.R
        Where C.RN = 1
        GROUP BY C.ID,C.Fund,C.RN,C.Dated )

select C.R,C.Fund,C.Dated,cc.Amt  from CTE4 C INNER JOIN CTE3 CC
ON c.R = cc.R
```